# How to setup a pr. job_type.Murnaghan that for each volume reads the structure output of another Murnaghan job?

Tags: pyiron

For the Ene-Vol calculations of the **non-cubic** structures, one has to relax the structures for all volumes.

Suppose that I start with a `pr.jobtype.Murnaghan()` job that its `ref_job_relax` is a cell-shape and internal coordinates relaxation. Let's call the Murnaghan job R1 with 7 volumes, i.e. R1-V1,...,R1-V7.

After one or more rounds of relaxation (R1...RN), one has to perform a static calculation to acquire a precise energy. Let's call the final static round S.
For the final round, I want to create a `pr.jobtype.Murnaghan()` job that reads all the required setup configurations from the `ref_job_static` except the **input structures** .
Then for each volume S-Vn it should read the corresponding output structure of RN-Vn, e.g. R1-V1-->S-V1, ..., R1-V7-->S-V7 if there were only one round of relaxation.

I am looking for an implementation like below:

```py
murn_relax = pr.create_job(pr.job_type.Murnaghan, 'R1')
murn_relax.ref_job = ref_job_relax
murn_relax.run()

murn_static = pr.create_job(pr.job_type.Murnaghan, 'S', continuation=True)
murn_static.ref_job = ref_job_static
murn_static.structures_from(prev_job='R1')
murn_static.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Murnaghan object has two relevant functions:

- `get_structure()` https://github.com/pyiron/pyiron_atomistics/blob/master/pyiron_atomistics/atomistics/master/murnaghan.py#L829
- `list_structures()` https://github.com/pyiron/pyiron_atomistics/blob/master/pyiron_atomistics/atomistics/master/murnaghan.py#L727

The first returns the predicted equilibrium structure and the second returns the structures at the different volumes.

In addition you can get the IDs of the children and iterate over those:

```
structure_lst = [
    pr.load(job_id).get_structure()
    for job_id in murn_relax.child_ids
]
```

to get a list of converged structures.

Comment: Thanks @Jan, but this is not what I am looking for.
The main point is how to set-up a Murnaghan job that uses these structures as input.
Currently, the Murnaghan job takes the structure of the `ref_job` and apply a range of strain on it to produce the structure for all required volumes.
I assume this is a feature request and might be implemented in the future.

Comment: `get_structure()` is only useful for the cubic structures and should not be used for non-cubic ones, because the equilibrium volume for non-cubic structure is not a simple isometric scaling of the `ref_job`'s structure. Cell-shape and internal coordinates might be different a bit. Otherwise there were no need for all these troubles in the first place.

Comment: The current `Murnaghan` module is designed to work with cubic structures, for non-cubic structures it is most likely easier to write your own for loop. Still we are definitely interested to extend the `Murnaghan` module in future.